# Linear model and confidence level issues in R

Tags: r, regression, linear

Please again accept my apologies for my little knowledge in R. I', trying to get better! you help me so much, but im a biologist and my statisc knowledge is sadly low

I have the following data set:

```
Perc_Reacting,Pulses,IndMutant,Proportion
93,1,1,0.93
81,2,1,0.81
73,3,1,0.73
64,4,1,0.64
73,5,1,0.73
68,6,1,0.68
64,7,1,0.64
65,8,1,0.65
50,9,1,0.5
68,10,1,0.68
57,11,1,0.57
50,12,1,0.5
62,13,1,0.62
44,14,1,0.44
54,15,1,0.54
56,16,1,0.56
50,17,1,0.5
42,18,1,0.42
42,19,1,0.42
29,20,1,0.29
96,1,0,0.96
100,2,0,1
92,3,0,0.92
96,4,0,0.96
92,5,0,0.92
92,6,0,0.92
84,7,0,0.84
96,8,0,0.96
91,9,0,0.91
82,10,0,0.82
86,11,0,0.86
82,12,0,0.82
91,13,0,0.91
85,14,0,0.85
83,15,0,0.83
70,16,0,0.7
74,17,0,0.74
64,18,0,0.64
68,19,0,0.68
78,20,0,0.78
```

Propose a linear model to study the association of the percentage response variable reaction (without any transformation) with the Pulses variable and the IndMutant factor. I'm a bit lost because the Lm() functions gives a very weak model. any help would be nice

Then, i need to Find the 95% confidence interval for the average percentage of mutants that react to 10 pulses of light in similar experimental conditions.

I'm a bit lost on how to approach this in R, I know is easy but I´m a bit stuck..

If anyone could help

thanks and kind regards

Comment: I cannot reproduce your claims: the `lm` model is what almost anyone would consider a very *strong* one, not a "very weak" one.  You will need to explain what you mean and show us the information you base this claim on.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the package `betareg` -> https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/vignettes/betareg.pdf

To install the package you can do:

```
install.packages("betareg")
library(betareg)
```

And then like in a linear regression you could run:

```
betareg(Perc_Reacting~Pulses+IndMutant, data)
```

I will say tho that I never used this package or run a beta regression myself

Comment: Won't work because OP's values are in the interval (0, 1] whereas beta regression only allows values in the interval (0, 1).